# weekly averages, rolling year

Tags: postgresql, average, rolling-computation

I need to calculate a rolling year average using Postgres SQL, I have the data by year, month and week as this (sample):

[image]

I need to calculate the weekly rolling average (this is the sum of units over the last year, and divide by the number of weeks that are present in that year).

So for example, if I'm on week 40 year 2020, I need to get the sum of all the weeks prior to this one, until week 40 2019 and divide by the total number of weeks in that range. I need this calculation as a new column on each row..
How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please show us the expected result of your input data. It is not clear what do you mean with "rolling average". For me it looks more "cumulative": Sum the units until the current week and divide it by the number of records until this week (= AVG)

Comment: I just edited my question to add more clarity on what I need

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using a [window function based on `RANGE`](https://modern-sql.com/de/blog/2019-02/postgresql-11) (since **PostgreSQL 11**):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=14132894429a55f202ee1336ca15c6d9)

```
SELECT
    *,
    AVG(unit) OVER (                                              -- 3
       ORDER BY to_date(y::text || '-' || w::text, 'IYYY-IW')     -- 1
       RANGE BETWEEN interval '1 year' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW  -- 2
    )
FROM
    t
```

1. Create an order criterion - it must be compatible to the chosen `RANGE` type. In that case we want a time range, so the order criterion must be a datetime type. In order to achieve this, we create a date from the year and the week (first create a date string, to be able to convert it using a date pattern)
2. Window function based on `RANGE`s: It allows to create the window size based on the date, no matter how many records exist. If you could ensure one record per week, you could use `ROWS BETWEEN 52 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` instead but it's less accurat because of the possible 53rd week in a year (possible solution for version prior v11)
3. Calculate the `AVG` over that window.

Comment: I need the average, but over the last weeks, so if I want to calculate for example rolling year avg of week 5, then I need to look back from week 4 2020 until week 5 2019 and calculate the avg of that

Comment: Changed the answer

Comment: Thanks it works partially, there are week numbers which repeat in the list, as some weeks is the same in 2 months, so I need to find a way to get the AVG by just the number of distinct week and not by week/month

Comment: You could GROUP or DISTINCT the weeks before doing the AVG calculation: `... FROM (SELECT SUM(w) FROM t GROUP BY w) s` or `... FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (w) * FROM t) s`